# TinyMCE is not supporting PHP , MySQL

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE to edit a Ajax loaded form. When I post the form with plain text then it comes on database. But when I try to style the texts (eg: Bold, Italic, etc), It not arrives also no mysql_error() generates. I'm using the below code to post the data to database (I tried using three method but any of the below not worked for me)

1) `stripslashes($_POST['msg'])`

2)

```
$allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img>';
$allowedTags.='<li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del>';
strip_tags($_POST['msg'], $allowedTags)
```

3) `htmlentities($_POST['msg'])`

and then I tried **var_dump($_POST['msg'])** and it showed **string("0")**;
then I removed ***tinyMCE*** javascript link, now it works fine. I couldn't understood what may be the problem ?

my TinyMCE integration code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="najupal.com/home/js/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced"
    });
</script>
```

please help me .

Comment: Can you try to describe in more detail what goes wrong? I don't understand. If you are trying to insert the data into a mySQL database, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is the way to go

Comment: Please read as well: [I have a question, what information should I provide so that somebody can help me with an answer?](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#I_have_a_question.2C_what_information_should_I_provide_so_that_somebody_can_help_me_with_an_answer.3F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i guess your text from texarea is not passed to the script if i understand this right?

I remember that i have such a problem a while ago using both ajax (xajax and TinyMCE)

Try to add this code into a button before any other function:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave(false, false);
```

In Xajax for example this is how it should look:

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Send Data" onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false, false);xajax_submitFunction(xajax.getFormValues('formID'));"/>
```

So try to call tinyMCE.triggerSave(false, false); function before posting data.

Hope i undertand this right and this will solve your problem.